# Is there an official Forgotten Realms map for D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, maps

Is there an official Forgotten Realms map out for D&D 5e yet? Any book or map I can purchase if it is not available online?

As of now, I have the Starter Set which comes with the just the Sword Coast region of Faerun around Neverwinter (The Craggs, Sword Mountains, etc). I would like to know how does it all fit in?

From what I have read up on this topic, from 3.5e to 4e, FR had lot of changes to the geography. And in 5e FR, some event happened (The Sundering) which kind of restored it to 3.5e FR but not fully?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a [map online](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/map-faer%C3%BCn) of the northwest corner of Faerun, but I don't believe there's an official map of all of the Forgotten Realms yet. As someone who's new to the game and setting, I find the [Forgotten Realms wikia](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Faer%C3%BBn) to be a great source of information, and it has a page for the [Second Sundering](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Sundering) which I believe is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the map in [chooban's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/95919/31489), there's a more detailed map of the Savage Frontier (which extends from the Sword Coast to the desert of Anauroch) in *Storm King's Thunder* on pg. 74-75. As pointed out by @DerekStucki in the comments, [a high-resolution digital version of this map](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/SKTPreview_map.jpg) is available for download for free online.

In fact, all of Chapter 3 in *Storm King's Thunder* details the Savage Frontier pretty well along with the map. I believe there is a special dungeon master screen for *Storm King's Thunder* which provides the map if you don't want to pay the full price for the book.

Comment: There is also a free high resolution download of this version of the map.

Comment: @DerekStucki Awesome! Where is it at? I'm about to be running Storm King's Thunder actually so that'd be an awesome resource.

Comment: http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/extralife2016

Answer (score 13):

Official stuff is always on [dnd.wizards.com](http://dnd.wizards.com), especially on their [Faerûn](http://dnd.wizards.com/dungeons-and-dragons/what-is-dd/forgotten-realms) page.

So there is Faerûn and in it we find the towns:

- Neverwinter (yes, **the** Neverwinter from Salvatore's [Drizzt Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drizzt_Do%27Urden), Neverwinter Nights [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Nights) & [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Nights_2), the [MMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Nights_(1991_video_game)) and finally the MMO [Neverwinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_(video_game)))
- Baldur's Gate (Yes, the one from the PC games [BG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldur%27s_Gate), [BG2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldur%27s_Gate), [BG:DA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldur%27s_Gate:_Dark_Alliance), [BG:DA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldur%27s_Gate:_Dark_Alliance_II), the Clark & Athans novels)
- Icewind Dale (which again, has [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icewind_Dale) and [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icewind_Dale_II) PC game, and a Book [trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Icewind_Dale_Trilogy)).
- Waterdeep (from [Eye of the Beholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Beholder_(video_game)) and a [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterdeep_(novel)))

But not yet the map... But wait! There is it! The official map in its very own article, a bit hidden! [Here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/map-faer%C3%BCn), ready for download! For FREE!
But wait, where's all the info? Oh, Do you want to know MORE! Is that map too tiny? Do you want it laminated and with more info? Run to your shop and get the [Sword Coast Adventure Guide!](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide)

Wait, you need special maps for Storm King's Thunder? Why didn't you say you in the beginning? [HERE!](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dungeon-masters-screen-0) The official one for this module, with a MAP on the inside! You're missing the module yet? missing what it is about? [Wizards can help!](http://dnd.wizards.com/dungeons-and-dragons/story/storm-kings-thunder) Really? You want me to tell? In short: ... it's a D&D Module! Yes, yes, I know, I am evil, but I do no spoilers!

*Year and day later...*

Apparently Mike Schley, the artist of the Tomb of Annihilation, ALSO provides maps for the forgotten realms in an official function (as prints & downloads) via his [own website](http://prints.mikeschley.com/). On that page, you surely will find the [Faerûn sub page](http://prints.mikeschley.com/p858006957), but I am nice and link it.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a [digital version](https://map.fantasymaps.org/toril/1302/2.4953838032766895/29.11300793900665/-69.08069265939677) of an enormous Toril map I found and I now have most of the major cities placed (not mapped), most rivers, all major and minor roads and I am now working on the digitization of the cities. Waterdeep is already there (Image 3), and others are coming.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this may be a generally helpful resource, I don’t think it’s appropriate for this question. The question is looking for an officially published map of the Forgotten Realms, and unless your work is endorsed by Wizards of the Coast, it isn’t an answer to the question.

Comment: I agree with Thomas, especially given the plug at "official" right in the question. Might I suggest **at least** answering the question asked first?

Comment: You mentioned finding an enormous Toril map. If you can direct us to it, that may answer the question!

Comment: Short reminder that this is a great resource that still answers the implied need in the question and qualifies as an answer. Unfortunately, it will rightly receive downvotes because it is not an official map. But if you also include the official state of the map and background information, the reception is likely to be much better.

Comment: you are right and this will be taken care of