# What official descriptions & maps exist for Neverwinter around 1489DR?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, maps

Thanks to the [Spellplague](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Spellplague) and the [Second Sundering](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Sundering) the city of Neverwinter has gone through massive changes since the previous editions. Thus much of the information about it, that was valid in earlier editions, now truly is *history*.

**What official WotC source(s) contain accounts, maps, and/or descriptions regarding the *current state* ([5th ed, ~1489DR](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82732/when-in-universe-does-5e-dd-take-place)) of Neverwinter?**

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95914/is-there-an-official-forgotten-realms-map-for-dd-5e that has not been closed, so I tried to formulate my goal as similar as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main source of current information about [Neverwinter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#Neverwinter) comes from the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* Chapter 2 under the heading of the same name in the section "The Lords' Alliance" (p. 51-53). It contains a reasonably detailed history and current status as well as a couple of maps (one being a partial world map and one of the city itself).

There is also a small amount of information in *Storm King's Thunder* [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/skt/the-savage-frontier#Neverwinter) (p. 101), but most of it is also in the above reference and there is no map. The city is even more briefly described and mentioned in *Princes of the Apocalypse* [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#Neverwinter) (p. 35-36) also with no map.

Note: I have refrained from quoting any of the material since you are asking simply about where it can be found and not any specific information about the city, and it would not be allowed or ethical to quote all the material here.

Comment: What about the descriptions of Xanathar? Do they add anything not covered by the SCAG?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T what  descriptions are you talking about precisely? I found no descriptions of Neverwinter that can be attributed to Xanathar in any source (including XGE).

Comment: Indeed I misremembered the sections from the SCAG being in Xanathar instead... :/

Comment: @dot_Sp0T yeah unfortunately SCAG is the only real setting book we have right now that would cover it and no adventures that I know of use Neverwinter as a primary setting so there isn't much more to it than that from what I can find.