# Is there a complete map of Faerûn?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, maps

Is there a complete map of all known places in Faerûn?

Many of the top-level maps don't have all locations (Helm's hold next to Neverwinter), Phandalin, and generally all of the locations that are marked in the DM maps (that are not on the players maps) are also very hard to find (if you don't know in what adventure to look for)

Is there a map with all known locations that either have an adventure taking place there or a dungeon or something similar?

For clarification: I'm looking for a spoiler-heavy DM map with the hidden locations, not for a player map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an official Forgotten Realms map for D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95914/14878)

Comment: For clarification, the map you are looking for would be pretty spoiler heavy, as many quests are about finding a specific location. Is that intended or would you rather have it spoiler free?

Comment: you are correct, I'm looking for the spoiler heavy map

Comment: I think this is a dupe of the Official Maps link by Purple Monkey. Both questions are asking for a map of Faerun. I think the right thing to do would be to bounty the duplicate asking for more details and if the maps contain all known locations. If you're okay with that, Frezzley, I'm happy to use my rep to bounty - just let me know!

Comment: sure, please do that

Comment: @Frezzley Bounty is up!